# If all values of $x$ such that the product $\left[x-\frac{1}{2}\right]\left[x+\frac{1}{2}\right]$ is prime,belongs to the set $[x_1,x_2)\cup[x_3,x_4)$

Tags: functions, prime-numbers

Let $[x]$ be the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.If all values of $x$ such that the product $\left[x-\frac{1}{2}\right]\left[x+\frac{1}{2}\right]$ is prime,belongs to the set $[x_1,x_2)\cup[x_3,x_4)$,find the value of $x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3+x^2_4$.

Since $\left[x-\frac{1}{2}\right]\left[x+\frac{1}{2}\right]$ is prime,therefore

either $\left[x-\frac{1}{2}\right]=1,\left[x+\frac{1}{2}\right]=p$(prime)
$1\leq x-\frac{1}{2}<2\Rightarrow 2\leq x+\frac{1}{2}<3$

I cannot find the intervals,since the prime $p$ is not specified.Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are completely on the right track. It turns out that $p$ cannot be just *any* prime: As you already found out, one option is that $[x-\frac12]=1$, so $\frac32\le x<\frac52$. As you also noted, this implies $2\le x+\frac12<3$, i.e., $[x+\frac12]=2$, so that indeed $[x-\frac12][x+\frac12]=1\cdot 2$ is prime for all $x\in[\frac32,\frac52)$.

The solution asks for the union of two half-open intervals - why? Recall that the product of two negative numbers is positive!

Comment: Thank you,sir.I got the answer.